# Solving the Knapsack problem in $O(n^2P)$, where P is the maximum weight of all items

Tags: graphs, dynamic-programming

Assume for the regular knapsack problem we have additional information - maximal weight of every item - lets denote it as P. Using this information, I want to solve the problem using dynamic programming in $O(n^2P)$.
Anyone have an idea how to solve it?

Comment: There is a common dynamic programming solution for knapsack which works in $O(nP)$. See in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem#Dynamic_programming_in-advance_algorithm)

Comment: I know about solution in $O(nW)$, I need in $O(n^2P)$

Answer (score 1):

If $W \ge n \cdot P$ you can add all elements in the knapsack.

Otherwise $W < n \cdot P$ in which case any algorithm with complexity $O(n W)$ will also have complexity $O(n \cdot (nP)) = O(n^2P)$. In particular the pseudo-polynomial dynamic programming solution described in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem#Dynamic_programming_in-advance_algorithm) works in $O(n W)$.

Comment: I'm not elaborating about the algorithm, since I think the key point of the answer was showing that it works in the expected complexity rather than showing how it works, and it is very known and available elsewhere.

Comment: Yes I know the algorithm, I didn't thought going that way of using the same algorithm, interesting point.